# MongoDB initialisation script not working properly

Tags: javascript, mongodb, docker, configuration

I have created a javascript file `config.js`, it is copied to `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/`

The script looks like this:

```
db.auth('root', 'root')
db = db.getSiblingDB('licensing')
db.admin.insert({data here})
```

When I do `docker-compose up -d` and check the logs I can see:

> /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: running
>   /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/config.js

But the database "licensing" is not created, and the data from insert is nowhere to be found...

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you get an Error? you might have to wait for the DB to be started before you can run these commands

Comment: @Neutrosider No, there was no error, and MongoDB is automatically starting this script while booting

Comment: Please add the docker-compose to reproduce the problem.